# Has anyone gotten Recaptcha to run on the Google App Engine (in Java)?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, recaptcha

I followed the recaptcha instructions and created a simple app that works if I run it in Eclipse using a local Tomcat server but the same files give an error (verify-params-incorrect) when validating the user's response when run in Eclipse using the local Google App Engine SDK.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the Java code linked to on the reCAPTCHA site? I took a quick look at it, and I suspect that the SimpleHttpLoader class uses some Java classes that are no allowed by Google's AppEngine.

So, here is what I know: Running locally, I get the same error as you.
But, when I deploy it to AppEngine, it works! For the forum posts I've read, I suspect it has to do with the remote IP address (127.0.0.1) when running locally.

Comment: Yes I am using the jar recaptcha4j-0.0.7.jar downloaded from: http://code.google.com/p/recaptcha/downloads/list?q=label:java-Latest

Comment: Hey, I'm still working on it. No luck so far, but I'll let you know what happens.

Answer (score 0):

This is sort of an impertinent answer, but are you sure you really need to pester your potential users with a captcha at all?  There's a great article over on sitepoint entitled "[10 Things to Check Before Using a CAPTCHA](http://www.sitepoint.com/captcha-alternatives/)"

Comment: It a good article and point of view definitely worth reading and think about I actually will next time I think about CAPTCHA usage. It just this is not the place... :-).

Comment: Depends on the usage of the captcha. What if I'm using it after three failed log-in attempts? That way I can prevent a brute force attack and I would be protecting my users, not "pestering" them.

Answer (score 0):

I had no problems at all locally with Google App Engine or deployed with recaptcha4j-0.0.8.jar and Google App Engine SDK 1.6.6. I followed the reCaptcha tutorial for Java at https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/java.

Check here for recaptcha4j lastest version: http://code.google.com/p/recaptcha4j/downloads/list